# AL value: nH/N² vs. nH/T²

Tags: inductor, inductance, coil, units

I'm in the process of sizing some toroidal ferrites. My problem is that I am seeing the AL value on the datasheets shown two different ways as nH/N² or nH/T².

Are these two units identical? I believe they are, being that N and T both stand for "turn".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, both N and T stand for turn.

Comment: That's good to hear. I found a value that was unexpectedly high on one of my datasheets with a different unit and was a little unsure. Thank you.

Comment: Not wishing to be overly pedantic, N and T stand for "turns" (plural).

Comment: Not wishing to be yet more pedantic, surely they stand for 'turn' when there is a single turn, and 'turns' when there are more than one?

Comment: Then why bother with the "^2" part. Also given that N really stands for "number of turns" calling it "number of turn" doesn't sound right!

Comment: It doesn't, does it! Not everything has to be put into Backus-Naur Form to be understood. The OP's context is adequate.